# Re-selecting another value and clac but old result displays in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm studying calc. I'm having problem with re-selecting value and calc.

Here is my whole program

https://jsfiddle.net/diessses/c9ykmsf2/6/

When user select value then press submit. it works perfectly. However when user change such as 'cb_amount' , s_month and 's_year' Then click submit below code part displays OLD result. Other part result works fine. Could you teach me write code please?

```
// PAY_START_END_MONTH_FMT message
const PAY_START_END_MONTH_FMT = "If loan start Month is :start ,<br> Final loan paying will be :end ";
let s_month = document.getElementById(elementId.s_month).value;
if (s_month) {
    let s_year = document.getElementById(elementId.s_year).value;
    let date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(s_month - 1);
    date.setFullYear(s_year);
    let startMonth = DateManager.formatDate(date, DateManager.getFormatString().YYYY_MM);

    DateManager.addMonth(date, (years * 12) - 1);
    let endMonth = DateManager.formatDate(date, DateManager.getFormatString().YYYY_MM);
    document.getElementById("pay_start_end_month").innerHTML = PAY_START_END_MONTH_FMT.replace(":start", startMonth).replace(":end", endMonth);
}

// CB_SENTENCE_FMT message
const CB_SENTENCE_FMT = "Combined bonus amount will be :j_actual_cb_ttl. Paying times is :j_cbTimes . mothly paying is :j_monthly_bns_payment";

if (bSecondToLastTtl > 1) {

let j_actual_cb_ttl = ValueUtils.comma(bSecondToLastTtl);
let j_cbTimes = cbTimes;
let j_monthly_bns_payment = ValueUtils.comma(monthly_b);    

document.getElementById("j_cb_sentence").innerHTML = CB_SENTENCE_FMT.replace(":j_actual_cb_ttl", j_actual_cb_ttl).replace(":j_cbTimes", j_cbTimes).replace(":j_monthly_bns_payment", j_monthly_bns_payment);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of variables which you are have declaration as "const". Try changing those to "let". Read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let. I have forked your code and tried, seems to be updating the data based on the new values.

Forked fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b5g73x02/. Below is what I changed.

```
let cbTimes = years * 2; //
let diff = amount - downpayment;

let justDevideCbAmount = cb_amount / cbTimes; 
let monthly_b = (Math.floor(justDevideCbAmount / 100) * 100); 
let bSecondToLastTtl = monthly_b * cbTimes;
let paymentTimes = years * 12; 
let interestMod = 10000 + (interest * 100); 
let ttlWInterest = parseInt(((amount - downpayment) * interestMod )/ 10000); 
let ttlWInterestNegativeCb = ttlWInterest - bSecondToLastTtl; 
let jstDevideMonthly = ttlWInterestNegativeCb / paymentTimes; 
let secondToLastMonthlyPayment = (Math.floor(jstDevideMonthly / 100) * 100); 
let firstMonthlyPayment = ttlWInterestNegativeCb - (secondToLastMonthlyPayment * (paymentTimes - 1));
let jKinri = (interest / 100).toFixed(5); 
let kinriFinal = ValueUtils.comma(parseInt(ttlWInterest - (amount - downpayment)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked very nicely. May I ask one question. when User type 0 at 'cb_amount'. Result still displays old data. Do you know why?

Comment: There is some issue with the way you set years value because eventually to calculate cbTimes you use years. Try checking that logic.

Comment: Thank you. I will look at it. I appreciate.